# Matlab split matrixes into equal parts till there is nothing more to split

Tags: matlab, matrix, split

I want to write an algorithm which splits matrix with size 128x128 into 4 equal pieces till there are nothing more to split and prints out the sum of 1 count in each matrix.

The sum count can simply be calculated with function `nnz(m)` where `m` is the matrix.

The split of the matrix 128x128 can be done with these functions

```
a = m(1:end/2, 1:end/2);
b = m(1:end/2, end/2+1:end);
c = m(end/2+1:end, 1:end/2);
d = m(end/2+1:end, end/2+1:end);
```

there a,b,c,d are the equal 4 parts of 128x128 matrix.

But how can I write a logic to loop that split so that it also splits those 4 matrixes to 4 equal parts, till there is nothing more to split?

Comment: Your formula requires the size to be 2^n, can we assume that is always true? For a small example (maybe 8x8), could you add the output structure you are expecting to the question? It seems you want some data from each layer.

Comment: Yes it is always true. I will always have an input of 128x128 size matrices. No other size of matrices will be used. Talking about the output it would be nice to have sum of 1 in each matrix for each of split level. For example after first split there would be 4 matrixes with such sums 16,16,16,16 after second split 16 matrixes with such sums 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 and so on. For me only those sums of 1ones in each matrix is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are approaching the problem a little to complicated. Instead of your algorithm one could use:
"Iteratively accumulate blocks of 2x2 until everything is accumulated to a 2x2 matrix"

```
x{1}=randi([0,1],8,8)
while size(x{end},1)>2
    x{end+1}=squeeze(sum(sum(reshape(x{end},2,size(x{end},1)/2,2,size(x{end},2)/2),1),3));
end
```

To explain the line in the loop. The `reshape` creates a 3d matrix, where for example `(1,:,1,:)` indexes the first block. Now having the data structured, `sum` is used to calculate the sum. Finally, we get a `[n,1,n,1]` matrix which is `squeez`ed to a `[n,n]` matrix.